# Why aren't options being overridden?

Tags: javascript

In my module pattern, options are 'undefined' for some reason.. does anyone see why they aren't being passed in properly?

```
Framework.MyModule = (function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        someOption : 1,
        stuff      : 2
    };
    if (!options) {
        var options = defaults;
    } else {
        for (var index in defaults) {
            if (typeof options[index] == 'undefined')
                options[index] = defaults[index];
        }
    }
    var module = {};

    // Initialize
    _something();

    // Private Methods
    function _something() {}

    // Public Methods
    module.click = function() {};

    return module;
})();


... docready function ...

var options = {
  someOption : 9,
  stuff      : 10
};

Framework.MyModule(options);

... end doc ready ...
```

Please see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kWHEZ/1/

Comment: Is there a reason you are self-executing the MyModule method after declaration?

Comment: I appreciate that you have provided some real code (or some semblance thereof). It would be helpful if you were able to go one step further and provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with a pared-down example reproducing your problem.

Comment: if I don't, I can't use the public method "Framework.MyModule.click()"

Comment: added fiddle to question

Comment: The way things are setup right now you need to set `Framework.MyModule(options)` to a `var` and it works http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/kWHEZ/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var options = { /* ... */};
Framework.MyModule = (function(options) {
  /* .. options are undefined ... */
})();

Framework.MyModule = (function(options) {
  /* .. options are defined... */
})(options);
```

Now if you want the ability to add private/public variables AND still pass options you will need to make it so the a constructor method is returned with your public object - thus not passing options in the function that is run immediately. Because lets be honest .. this doesn't *really* make sense.

---

You could do something like this:

```
var Module = {};
Module.Foo = (function($){ // jQuery is accessible as $
    var _private = {
        defaults: {
            url: '/default-url', container: '#dummy'
        },
        foos: []
    };

    return function(o){ // returns constructor
        // other _private variables are accessible here
        var opts = $.extend({}, _private.defaults, o);
        var self = { // public return object
            load: function(){
                $(opts.container).load(opts.url);
            }
        };
        _private.foos.push(self);
        return self;
    };
})(jQuery); // scope global variables


var foo1 = Module.Foo({
    url: '/test.php', 
    container: '#success'
});

var foo2 = Module.Foo({
    url: '/test2.php', 
    container: '#success2'
});

foo1.load();
foo2.load();
```

Comment: can you elaborate on how to add both? I believe this is what I need to do.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @tester - I elaborated with an update to the answer. There are many ways you could do this.

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing in any options to the anonymous function call.

your call would have to end with `})(options);` if you want it to use custom options.

Answer (score 1):

You're executing the function immediately. That function returns module, which is an object, not a function. Did you mean instead to return a function?

Then call it using:

```
Framework.MyModule(options);
```